# Using ZXing in Unity to locate QRcode's Position Pattern

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zxing

As the title, i want to use locate three Position Pattern.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUR1C.png)

I want to know how to get the x y position of those pattern when I got a new QR code from a webcamtexture.
How should I implement this is Unity(C#)?

Comment: You can refer [this blog](https://medium.com/@adrian.n/reading-and-generating-qr-codes-with-c-in-unity-3d-the-easy-way-a25e1d85ba51) to understand better.

Comment: This blog only show how to decode and encode by ZXing(already done this part before),but still don't know how to get position of patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code for decoding ZXing dll.

```
private WebCamTexture camTexture;
private Rect screenRect;
void Start()
{
    screenRect = new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height);
    camTexture = new WebCamTexture();
    camTexture.requestedHeight = Screen.height;
    camTexture.requestedWidth = Screen.width;
    if (camTexture != null)
    {
        camTexture.Play();
    }
}

void OnGUI()
{
    // drawing the camera on screen
    GUI.DrawTexture(screenRect, camTexture, ScaleMode.ScaleToFit);
    // do the reading — you might want to attempt to read less often than you draw on the screen for performance sake
    try
    {
        IBarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();
        // decode the current frame
        var result = barcodeReader.Decode(camTexture.GetPixels32(), camTexture.width, camTexture.height);
        if (result != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("DECODED TEXT FROM QR: " +result.Text);
        }
        ResultPoint[] point = result.ResultPoints;
        Debug.Log("X: " + point[0].X + " Y: " + point[1].Y);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Debug.LogWarning(ex.Message); }
}
```

I had taken reference from [ZXing dll link](https://github.com/nenuadrian/qr-code-unity-3d-read-generate). It also has qr code generator in readme. Go through readme. Its almost same just `ResultPoint[] point = result.ResultPoints;` has been added to it. This gives the position of the 3 corners of image. Obviously you will need to add the ZXing.dll in plugins folder in the Assets.
 Hope this helps to get the result.

Comment: I had tried decoding QR marker from ZXing a year and half ago on android and pc so it did worked for me at that time. Dont know now but should be able to work with ios also.